# Is there a way to force "Yes" to any prompts when running command with yarn run / nx run

Tags: cmd, yarnpkg, nrwl-nx, nrwl

As the title suggests, I would like to know if there is an option that I can use to force "yes" when a prompts appears after launching a command with `yarn run` or `nx run`.

Example:

`yarn run nx run command`
`nx run command`

Prompts:

`Port 4200 is already is use. Would you like to use a different port? (Y/n)`

I would like the answer to this question to always be yes.

Thank you!

P.s:
I use nx to manage a monorepo of angular. My operating system is currently windows and my editor is VS Code.

Edit: With `echo Y | yarn run command` everything works fine. Thanks to @aschipfl 's comment!

Comment: Depending on the executable, you may pipe something into the prompt, given that it reads from _STDIN_ (handle `0`): `echo Y| yarn …`…

Comment: OMG it works! I kept typing `echo 'yes'` as if I were in a linux terminal and it didn't work. Thanks!